# Problems with the Prediction Interval in a Negative Binomial Regression

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

Sorry if this question is a little basic, but I don't know much about count regression.

I have my data, y, that follows a Negative Binomial distribution. I have many independent variables, in a matrix x.

So, in R, I'm writing:

```
model = glm.nb(y ~ x, data=data, link=log)
```

And I'm interested in the distribution of my predictions, so I did a test with 95% confidence interval.

```
tfit <- predict(model, newdata=data, se.fit=TRUE)
upperbound.fit <- exp(tfit$fit+1.96*tfit$se.fit)
lowerbound.fit <- exp(tfit$fit-1.96*tfit$se.fit)
```

In my mind, this would mean that 95% of my predictions should be between the upperbound and the lowerbound, but this is not happening (not even close), so clearly I misunderstood the theory.

Could you point to where am I wrong?

Comment: I am replying to a very old thread, but the issue is that the `predict.glm()` function (called via `predict()` on a GLM object) generates a 95% *confidence interval around the mean* - this is not a 95% prediction interval. It seems like generating a prediction interval for GLMs is not easy.